# Malformed line 1 in source list error

Tags: apt, ros

i wanted to install the husky robot to use it in gazebo

**sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-husky-simulator**

but i got this error

**E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.**

Comment: You did something wrong when you created `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list`. Review that and fix it.